# How do I undo a heroku create that was run over existing app?

Tags: git, heroku

I have been using heroku for deploying my app for a while.  I'm at the point where I want to create a new environment for staging.  Hoping to solicit usage instructions, I ran `heroku create`.  It turns out this is all that is needed to create an app:

```
Creating sleepy-chamber-3162... done, stack is cedar
http://sleepy-chamber-3162.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:sleepy-chamber-3162.git
```

I don't think this is what I wanted.

So what have I done?  My git branches and history seem to be intact, but I suspect my remote might be pointing to the new app.

How do I undo the changes done by `heroku create`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like `heroku create` creates the new app, but doesn't affect any of the app's files, git metadata, or even default remote paths.

```
heroku apps:destroy -a sleepy-chamber-3162
```

seems to be sufficient to undo the create.